# Query to select all fields inserted in the last 30 minutes actually selects every row

Tags: php, mysql

Basically this query should select all the fields inserted in the last 30 minutes, but it doesnt, it selects absolutely every row making my script output wrong data

```
SELECT count(*) FROM mytable 
WHERE `time` >= DATE_SUB(UTC_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 30 minute)
```

My *time* field stores the time in this kind of format *2011-06-08 22:32:03*

The query works, but it selects every row, not the ones inserted in the last 30 minutes.

Comment: what datatype is the column "time"?

Comment: This shouldn't work at all.  It should output a single row with a count.  Is this the behavior you want?  If so, you should update your question to reflect that.

Comment: Please post your create table syntax and some sample rows.

Comment: @rockerest- it should output the number of rows in the last 30 minutes afaik, but it outputs the count of nearly all the rows.

Comment: Is the timestamp in your database also UTC? Maybe you need to be adding a timezone offset?

Comment: @dikidera could you update your question to indicate that you want the count?  It's not really a huge issue, but your question pretty clearly states that it should "select all the fields" which just isn't the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add parentheses to your query - `UTC_TIMESTAMP()` or use `NOW()` - quite simpler for me.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
SELECT count(*) FROM mytable 
WHERE `time` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 minute)
```

Comment: This tells me that the time column is not UTC which would mean that he's getting the time difference between UTC and local time.

Comment: Your right, given his example I thought it was using a standard datetime field instead. He should be using UTC_TIMESTAMP() as per @Dave and @Tomasz Kowalczyk suggestion.